# Django & beforeunload event

Tags: javascript, django

I wanted to use the following code to fade the page out when the beforeunload event is fired.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
    $(document.body).fadeOut(600);
});
```

I noticed that the page fades as expected when leaving and going to a different site, but the page does not fade when going from one app in my Django-powered site to another.

Can anyone explain this behavior to me? I am just curious as to how Django is not causing the beforeunload event to fire.

Comment: Are you using any kind of SPA framework like Vue or Angular?

Comment: I'm not using any SPA frameworks.

Comment: Could you check your network tab and see if all of the resources are (re)loaded?